# How to use Vertex Buffer Objects

Tags: c++, opengl

Imagine I want to draw a pyramid made of triangles.

-Should I create a VBO for each triangle or one containing all triangles?

Comment: According to my tests i made once, over 1MB buffers start to slow down rendering, I usually use 512k buffers or less, just to play it safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecting a VBO into a context is a rather expensive state change, so using fewer VBOs is definitely advantageous.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But should I then feed the vbo an array of all vertices of all faces? (same vertex will be given more than one time)

Comment: @JoãoSilva yes, you should, but to avoid duplicated vertices, you should use [indexed rendering](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml), this will not only reduce the size of vbo, but also make it more likely you hit the [post-transform-cache](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Post_Transform_Cache)

Comment: Also see [this guide](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices)

Comment: Careful... vertices may not be repeated even if they overlap.  Even if the `x,y,z` coordinates are the same, the normal vector probably is not.